# Javasctipt object to array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object which is like `[ 'Country 1', 'Country 2' ]` When I console log the type of that it gives me 'object'. I want to convert that to an array.

I used this :

```
const arr = Object.values(countries);
console.log(typeof arr); //Still give me object
```

How can I get an array from that?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, but `"array"` is not output you can ever get from JS's built-in `typeof` operator. It has a fixed, very limited, set of outputs, and for any object other than a function (and an array is an object in JS) it will simply say "object". So you already have an array here, and shouldn't worry that the `typeof` operator correctly gives you `"object"` when used on it.